# Creating a custom EditForm for a document library

Tags: document-library, custom-list, list-definition, edit-form

I have been following this article: http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/

I have followed every step, my library is created and has a view. The custom EditForm.aspx is deployed to the right location in the hive (under the definition folder below the feature).

However, when i add a document sharepoint cannot find the edit form.

Error below - it seems to be looking the the current /Subsite/Subsite/Document Library/EditForm.aspx.

[image]

Any help appreciated as i've been racking my brains at this all day :S

***UPDATED***

Error was related to masterpage reference on custom editform page - the correct reference is below:

```
MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
```

Ok, my custom edit form is being used however, SP is ignoring my field re-arrangement (I wanted to change order of fields and hide some others).

I did not delete the DataFormWebpart from my edit form instead i modified the existing one - i guess sharepoint is removing it at runtime and adding its own???!

The author of the article created a part two - which explains exactly what I required: http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project-part-2/

In the end, it was an incorrect reference to the masterpage - sorry!

thanks,

KS

Comment: What does the `<Forms>` part of your schema.xml contain?

Comment: Updated with forms markup. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Url="EditForm.aspx"` attribute from `<Form Type="EditForm" .../ >`

Comment: No, sharepoint doesnt like that either - it needs to use that name but internally points to the custom form (according to the article). I did try removing it and sharepoint blew up - i am attaching the new error.

Comment: Try setting it to `Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx"`

Comment: Tried that too! It goes back to the first popup error - 404 <sigh>

Comment: Ok, checked out the log files and the error is related to the masterpage not being found - doh! Its looking for masterpage in the lists forms directory!

Comment: When I change the reference to /_layouts/applicationv4.master i get a "file is not allowed on this page" (something like that). How can i reference my cusomt masterpages that are on the site?

Comment: MasterPageFile should be set to `"~masterurl/default.master"`

Comment: Ah ok - that made the errors go away - the edit form is still the standard one tho :S I'll post my customedit form code.